# Validate an XmlDocument using an XSD String in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, xmldocument

I have an `XmlDocument` in C# that I need to validate against an Xml Schema. I've seen a lot of articles on how to do this using `XmlDocument.Schemas.Add(namspace, xsdfilename)`, however my XSD is not saved on the disk, it's in memory (loaded in from a database). Can anyone give me pointers on how to validate an `XmlDocument` with a XSD string?

Comment: Can you post code showing what you are currently using (or the system which uses a file)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using (StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xsdString))
using (XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
{
    xmlDocument.Schemas.Add(null, xmlReader);
}
```